# Need information on Adequat.NET

Tags: c#, .net

I just started a new project and they're using a .Net libarary called Adequat.NET. I can't seem to find any documentation on Google or Bing.

It appears to be a framework to manage Typed Datasets and XML and written for .Net 2.0

Can someone point be to a link of the company a developer? 
Or a migration path?

Answer (score 2):

The best I have come up with so far are a some CVs.

- [Someone who apparently worked on the project](http://summ-it.tripod.com/ENG/cv.htm)
- [Someone else who worked on it (PDF)](http://vandongen.polskin.be/files/CV%20Frank%20Van%20Dongen%20-%20English.pdf)

Those are two examples. There were a few others. From these I garnered the company that seems to have presided over the project and a rough idea of the project's purpose.

I have looked up the associated company [Real Software](http://www.realsoftware.com/) but can find no mention of Adequat.net. I did however, find [this annual report (PDF)](http://bib.kuleuven.be/ebib/data/jaarverslagen/RealSoftware_2000%281%29eng.pdf) that seems to discuss ADEQUAT (Application Development Quality Tools) - perhaps a precursor to Adequat.NET?

I doubt this is going to assist you much, but maybe you'll find some clues from this information to help you out. My best guess is that Adequat is now rolled up inside Real Software's Real Studio product. You could try contacting Real Software to see if they have any support documentation available.